# how to invoke notification by alarm manager

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I want to invoke notification by using a alarm receiver activity. When alarm receiver activity invoked the notification should be displayed on my screen. Can i use Notification Manager in alarm receiver activity?

Answer (score 0):

yes..you can invoke notification using the NotificationManager in receiver class..and should register the broadcast in manifest.xml